# tl9200 usb ethernet driver problem?

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, usb-modem

My house was struck by lightning which destroyed my adsl/router and landline phone. To my surprise my computer (which is connected but turned off when the lightning strike ) is still working, only the lan was destroyed. Now landline and router has been replaced and I bought a USB lan adapter. The problem the USB lan adapter is detected but not registered.

in my windows 7 laptop the usb lan is detected and registered automatically(no driver was installed by me) in device manager as:Tlink 9200 USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter #2

Please see the dmesg, lsusb and lswh output.

dmesg output:

```
[ 8137.931507] usb 5-1.4.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 8138.040267] usb 5-1.4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=e202, idProduct=9200
[ 8138.040276] usb 5-1.4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 8138.040281] usb 5-1.4.4: Product: USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
```

ifconfig -a output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15717 (15.7 KB)  TX bytes:15717 (15.7 KB)
```

no output: sudo lshw -C network

lsusb output

```
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0c23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0101:0007  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 008: ID e202:9200  
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 0e8d:1806 MediaTek Inc. Samsung SE-208AB Slim Portable DVD Writer
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am aware that some USB ethernet has no linux driver. Do you think in my case that should just buy another brand of USB lan adapter?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: Please add also output of `usb-devices | awk '/9200/' RS=`

Comment: "Do you think in my case that should just buy another brand of USB lan adapter?" After doing research on your e202:9200 device, I think the answer is yes, please buy a supported device. Sorry.

Comment: @chili555 Why do you think it is not supported? What is the chip there?

Comment: @Pilot6 I searched for e202:9200 and found nothing whatever that's useful.

Comment: @Pilot6
Hi Pilot6, Here is the output. 
FYI: I can connect to the internet now. I bought a pci via rhine card.. 

T:  Bus=05 Lev=03 Prnt=03 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=e202 ProdID=9200 Rev=01.01
S:  Product=USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=120mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

Comment: @Pilot6

Since I can connect to the internet now. I think I will have to store the usb-ethernet card I bought. Maybe in the next version of ubuntu this can be supported.